# NTFS external drive showing corrupted files (that are not corrupted) on Linux-based systems

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I'm using a Seagate Expansion 6TB drive on Linux, NTFS-formatted (For easy handling in both Linux and Windows machines), which I intend to use for upgrading my Linux based NAS running on an RPi3.

My problem is that whenever I mount this both on the Pi or on a Linux distro on an x86 computer, it thinks some of the video files I intend to share on the network are corrupted, but in fact they are NOT (Windows 10 reads them just fine).

Even MediaInfo on Linux reports the files as having missing audio or video tracks, which isn't true, since Windows plays them all perfectly. I have been trying several distros and several different Pis but I just can't do this; whenever it's Linux handling the drive, it gives me these weird problems. Obviously, I can't use it as a NAS if it won't even read all the files I intend to share properly. I also tried mounting using NTFS-3G instead of mount.ntfs, but same result.

Edit: I'm attempting to do further testing and I noticed that I can't even run the md5sum program on the "corrupted" files on Linux. It just gives me an i/o error on the terminal.

The drive itself is good, I was able to reboot back to Windows, download WinMD5 and compute an MD5 for one of the files that Linux thinks are corrupted.

Edit #2: OK, I've just disabled Hibernation and Fast Startup on Windows 10 (I don't like them anyway) only S3 sleep is enabled now according to `powercfg -a`. Then I turned off the computer, powered it back on, and went back to Linux. The files are still showing up as corrupted.

Edit #2: I use the same USB3 enclosure both on the computer and on the Pi. The drive is a 6TB Barracuda drive, I opened the enclosure to check if the USB3 circuitry was integrated with the drive itself. Nope, standard SATA drive inside it.

Also, chkdsk reports no problems across reboots when testing whether the files are readable in both Windows and Linux, with only Linux showing issues.

What could be happening here?

Comment: Have you disabled the hibernation file within Windows?  Specifically hybrid shutdown.  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Edited the OP. Would you rather have my questions answered like this?

Comment: Are you correctly dismounting the HDD before unplugging it from the PC (i.e. Safely Remove Hardware)?  Have you ran `ChkDsk` on the drive (`chkdsk /offlinescanandfix <driveletter>:`)?

Comment: @JW0914 Yes. I haven't run chkdsk with that parameter though, I used chkdsk <driveletter>: /f whenever it got corrupted (sometimes inevitable when testing across several different computers). Gonna try that flag and see what it does.

Comment: If you're correctly dismounting the drive in Windows via Safely Remove Hardware on the Taskbar _before_ unplugging the drive from the PC, there should be no corruption at all, regardless if mounting/dismounting on Windows or Linux (at least if using `ntfs-3g`).  Have you checked the drive's S.M.A.R.T data via installing `smartmontools` _(`smartctl -a /dev/<disk>`)_ and ran a long S.M.A.R.T test _(`smartctl -t long /dev/<disk>`; will take several hours, check progress via `smartctl -a /dev/<disk> | grep progress` and re-run `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` once testing has completed)_?